# mysql_fetch_row : how does it know which row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to get to grips with PHP and MYSQL programming, but after seeing an example, I cant understand how `mysql_fetch_row` knows which row to return. For example:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result); //gets the rows refering to the query

echo $row[0]; //returns the data in column 1

?>
```

In the code above, `echo $row[0];` returns the data in the first column in the table, but how does it know which row to take this data from (assuming the query returns more than one row)?

Moreover, if I put the code in a loop:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";
$result = mysql_query($query);

for ($j = 0 ; $J < 4 ; ++$j)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0];
}

?>
```

The values echoed are the values in (row1,column1) (row2,column1,) (row3,column1). How does this work if the incremented value `$j` isnt directly affecting the `mysql_fetch_row` function??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It advances to the next row each time you call it, which is why it's typically used in a `while` loop

Comment: ahh ok!, so if the query returned say 10 rows, and the function wasnt in a loop it would only return the 1st row from the database?

Comment: You can call it multiple times without a loop. The first call returns the first row, the second call returns the second row, and so on.

Comment: No, not the 1st but just one. Which one is undefined, unless you order the rows inside the query. Then there would be a 1st and 2nd and so on by that ordering, and the fetch would now return the 1st row.

Comment: It would only give you the single next row, yes. Call it again and you get the second row. When you do `while( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )` it sets `$row` to the next record each iteration of the loop

Comment: I didn't got what pid means. Are you saying the fetch_row will return the rows randomly? Regardless the query has order by or not the result set has a first row and a last row. So, when you call mysql_fetch_row in a very first time, it will bring the 1st row in the record set.

Comment: It iterates the rows in the order they were returned by MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

you nust have to add a "where" to your select:

for example:

> $value="mozart";
>
> $query = " SELECT * FROM classics where author='$value' ";

the sentence is: select all data from classics where the author is mozart